# Load data SQlite into htmlString iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have an app that reads from sqlite database,data is read and included in the objects using this method ....I checked with NSLog

```
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "Ricetta.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


static sqlite3_stmt *leggiStatement = nil;

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1

@synthesize Webmain, oggetto2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    //percorso file su cartella documents
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Rice.sqlite"];

    //controllo se il file esiste
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        //se non esiste lo copio nella cartella documenti
        NSString *pathLocale=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Rice" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:pathLocale toPath:path error:nil] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"copia eseguita");
        }       
    }





    [self personalizzaAspetto];


    [self carica_ID];




   // NSString * query = @" SELECT Immagine, Titolo, Descrizione FROM LIBRO";
   // NSArray * arrayQuery = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Immagine",@"Titolo",@"Descrizione",nil];
   // NSArray * arrayElementi = [self caricaValoriMain:query :arrayQuery];




        Webmain= [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 365)];
        NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
                               "<head> \n"
                               "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                               "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                               "</style> \n"
                               "</head> \n"
                               "<body><center><img src='%@'/></center></body><center><h1>%@</h1></center><body bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\" text=\" #ffa500\">%@</body></html>" ,@"futura",[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],oggetto2.Immagine,oggetto2.Titolo,oggetto2.Descrizione];

        [Webmain loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

        [self.view addSubview:Webmain];







-(void)carica_ID{




      sqlite3 *database = NULL;

      NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Rice.sqlite"];

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(leggiStatement==nil){
        const char *sql = "select Immagine,Titolo,Descrizione from LIBRO WHERE RicettaID=1";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &leggiStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
           NSAssert1(0, @"Errore creazione compiledState '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            }


            //while(sqlite3_step(leggiStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(leggiStatement))
            {




                NSString *titolo = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(leggiStatement, 1)];
                NSLog(@"%@",titolo);
                oggetto2.Titolo=titolo;

                NSString *descrizione = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(leggiStatement, 2)];
                NSLog(@"%@",descrizione);
                oggetto2.Descrizione = descrizione;

                NSString *image= [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(leggiStatement, 0)];
                NSLog(@"%@",image);
                oggetto2.Immagine= image;



        }

        sqlite3_finalize(leggiStatement);
    }

 sqlite3_close(database);

}



@end
```

My problem is that I can not put them in webMain...objects in webMain remain empty.

I do not use Xib.

Comment: If you are not using a xib, why did you implement the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method?

Comment: I think it is not really implemented...

Comment: When you say that the web view is empty, do you see anything, such as a broken link and references to "(null)"? Or is it literally empty, completely blank, all white and nothing showing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet provided, you never perform the `alloc` and `init` of `oggetto2`. Thus, it is `nil`, and thus attempts to set its properties will achieve nothing.

In addition to your existing `NSLog` statements, I'd also suggest doing a `NSLog` of the `htmlString` right before you perform `loadHTMLString`, because it's easier to see what's going on with your HTML by looking at the source, rather than trying to make inferences from a blank web view.

---

Unrelated to your problem, but you probably should not have code that could potentially reusing your static `sqlite3_stmt` after you've finalized it. The first time you call `carica_ID` you would initialize the static `leggiStatement`. But you end up doing a `sqlite_finalize` but don't set `leggiStatement` to `nil`. If you ever called this method a second time, it won't `sqlite3_prepare_v2` again, but you will have freed the resources associated with your prior `leggiStatement`.

A couple of easy fixes:

- do not make `leggiStatement` a static global, but rather make it a local, non-static variable of the method;
- if you do `sqlite3_finalize`, make sure you set `leggiStatement` to `nil` as well; or
- don't call `sqlite3_finalize`, but rather just call `sqlite3_reset`, which will reset the prepared statement, but won't release its resources.

Comment: I set sqlite3_finalize to sqlite3_reset, leggiStatement as non static variable... Unfortunately no change...I also set NSlog check before loadHTMLString...object remain empty

Comment: @geminimac Have you added the `alloc` and `init` of `oggetto2`? That `sqlite3_finalize` issue was a secondary issue (though important). It strikes me that `oggetto2` was the main issue.

Comment: great!! ... you have been wonderful ... you're a genius!
I initialize the object like this: oggetto2= [[Ricetta alloc]initWithPrimaryKey:0]....worked!Thank you!